# In HTML Canvas can a single path have different stroke properties?

Tags: html5-canvas

is there a way to have different segments of a path have different properties, especially color? What I'd like to do is something like the following code, but this code it will only remember the last color selected. I can break it into individual paths but then I lose the ability to have the line join property create a smooth line.

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvasElement");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");     

ctx.beginPath();     
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";    // sets the color
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#00ff00";    // overrides color. 
ctx.lineTo(50, 300);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Each path has only one set of styles (==the last style applied).

But even with `lineJoin` multiple stroke colors would visually break up the polyline.

Anyway, perhaps use `lineCap` as a substitute for `lineJoin`.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.lineWidth=6;

drawSegment(20,40,80,20,'red');
drawSegment(80,20,140,40,'green');
drawSegment(140,40,35,140,'blue');


function drawSegment(x0,y0,x1,y1,strokeColor){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
  ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.strokeStyle=strokeColor;
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```